# change the order of a string in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to change the order of a string like :
name/surname by surname/name OR name/ surname by surname/ name (taking account on spaces after/)

below my request.but the second part is wrong :

```
select SUBSTR ('name/surname' , INSTR ('name/surname','/')+1)  ||SUBSTR ('name/surname' , 1,INSTR('name/surname','/')-1) 
from dual
```

Comment: MySQL and/or Oracle? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using a regular expression**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( 'name/surname', '^(.*?)/(.*)$', '\2/\1' ) FROM DUAL;
```

or trimming all whitespaces:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( ' name / surname ', '^\s*(.*?)\s*/\s*(.*?)\s*$', '\2/\1' ) FROM DUAL;
```

or preserving a whitespace before and after the slash (and trimming leading/training whitespace):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( ' name / surname ', '^\s*(.*?)(\s?/\s?)(.*?)\s*$', '\3\2\1' ) FROM DUAL;
```

**Using string functions:**

```
WITH names ( text ) AS (
  SELECT 'name/surname' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT SUBSTR( text, INSTR( text, '/' ) + 1 ) || '/' || SUBSTR( text, 1, INSTR( text, '/' ) - 1 )
FROM   names;
```

or trimming whitespace:

```
WITH names ( text ) AS (
  SELECT ' name / surname ' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT TRIM( SUBSTR( text, INSTR( text, '/' ) + 1 ) ) || '/' || TRIM( SUBSTR( text, 1, INSTR( text, '/' ) - 1 ) )
FROM   names;
```

Comment: Hi It working well.but i might have a space like :name/ surname.In this case what should i added to the request above?

Comment: Is the space causing you a particular issue?

Comment: Hi I may have in input name/ surname or name/surname the request should be work for both of them.I have to take into consideration the space between the / and the surname

Comment: @user2425416 I have included versions that will respect space or will trim spaces.

Comment: Hi requests below are not working fine for both : name/ surname or name/surname.My target is to put : name/ surname and having as result : surname/ name or to put name/surname in input and having as result surname/ name

Comment: @user2425416 See the 3rd regular expression query.

Comment: That's because nowhere in your requirements did you specify that format... updated again

Comment: I need a function that can change the order of the string separated by / taking account of the spaces

Comment: As I said... I've updated the answer again. However, this isn't a code writing service so you ought to try modifying the queries yourself.

Comment: Hi It's working well now.Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

select substr('firstname/lastname',instr('firstname/lastname','/')+1)||'/' 
|| substr('firstname/lastname',1,instr('firstname/lastname','/')-1) from dual;

Comment: Hi It doesn't work : i received /lastname firstname/ instead of : lastname/firstname

Comment: can you give me a data reference for example what is your original data and how you want to modify in sql query